# Windows batch file - Variables in nested FOR loops

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I've a list of users in a text file (users.txt) and I want, for each user, to copy every file in their directory (c:\Folder\*username*) and subdirectory in another directory without subdirectory (c:\Folder 2\*username*).

I'm now using a batch file containing something like this:

```
for /f %%u in (user.txt) do (
    for /r "C:\Folder\%%u" %%f in (*.*) do @xcopy "%%f" "C:\Folder 2\%%u" 
)
```

...but is not working.

After some tests I was able to find out what's wrong: the first %%u variable in the second FOR

```
for /r "C:\Folder\%%u" %%f in (*.*) do @xcopy "%%f" "C:\Folder 2\%%u"
```

is not correctly replaced by the *username*.
Instead the second %%u (inside the DO command) is correctly replaced by it's value.

Is there a way to force the first %%u variable to take the correct value?

Comment: How will you deal with filename collisions if two files with the same name exist in different folders?

Comment: FOR /F quoted options cannot use FOR variables or delayed expansion. It has to do with the order in which various parsing phases take place.

Comment: @foxidrive There should not be collisions (at least for what I'm doing now), so I didn't think about how to deal with it. Anyway if I need to do it I think the best way will be to transform the path to the file to it's name.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%u in (user.txt) do (
        pushd "C:\Folder\%%u" && (
            for /r %%f in (*) do @xcopy /i /y "%%f" "c:\Folder 2\%%u\" 
            popd
        )
    )
```

One simple solution is to remove the first `for` replaceable parameter from the recurse clause of the second `for`

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by calling a subroutine instead of nesting the loops. Something like:

```
for /f %%u in (user.txt) do call :doxcopy %%u
goto :eof

:doxcopy
for /r "C:\Folder\%1" %%f in (*.*) do @xcopy "%%f" "C:\Folder 2\%1" 
goto :eof
```