# Batch file: For loop that recurses directory, has directory wildcard, and file wildcard

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

**In short:** how do I run a command for each file matching `proto/acme*/**/*.proto`, where "`**`" means recursive subdirectory depth?

**Longer details:**

I have a directory structure like this:

```
proto\
    acme_bar\
        l.proto
    acme_foo\
        abc\
            a.proto
            b.proto
        xyz\
            x.proto
    rand_rar\
        q.proto
```

I would like a batch file that runs the following (but works even if the current list of files changes, obviously):

```
protoc proto\acme_bar\l.proto
protoc proto\acme_foo\abc\a.proto
protoc proto\acme_foo\abc\b.proto
protoc proto\acme_foo\xyz\x.proto
rem NOT protoc proto\rand_rar\q.proto!
```

I currently have two pieces of the puzzle (replace each `%` with `%%` for a batch file rather than on the command line):

```
rem returns proto\acme_bar and proto\acme_foo
for /d %d in (proto\acme*) do echo %d
rem returns *.proto, recursing through all directories
for /r %p proto in (*.proto) do echo %p
```

What I want is a for loop that iterates over all `*.proto` files, but only in `proto\acme_*`. A single for loop that does this would be ideal, but alternatively a nested for loop would do (with `proto\acme*` in the outer loop and `**\*.proto` on the inside), but I can't figure out how to get that to work.

An alternative idea would be to just recursively find all `*.proto` and then have an `if` statement inside that checks whether the file starts with `proto\acme_`. The number of false matches would be small enough that this wouldn't be a problem speed wise. A complication is that `for /r` seems to return absolute paths, but a solution that matches `proto\acme_` anywhere in the file name would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26273997/7008416) to a similar (but not exactly the same) question. To avoid the problem of using the variable from the outer loop in the conditional of the inner loop, you change directory in the loop:

```
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
FOR /D %%D in (proto\acme_*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%D" && (
        FOR /r %%P in (*.proto) DO (
            protoc %%P
        )
        POPD
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: @dbenham How does the inner for loop know that it should look in `%%D`? BTW the snippet turns delayed expansion *off*

Comment: OMG - sorry about the delayed expansion non-issue - I obviously didn't read carefully :-/ And my snippet was typed in incorrectly, but even the corrected form doesn't work :( I mistakenly thought you could use `for /d %%D in (proto\acme_*) do for /r "%%D" %%P in (*.proto) do protoc "%%P"`. But that cannot work because the path after the `/R` option must be known at the time the command is parsed. But the `"%%D"` value isn't known until iteration has begun. So my comments were a waste of your time - sorry.

Comment: @dbenham Don't worry about it :-)